# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' in Tensorflow code

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

everyone.

I tried to write mnist recognition code.

however, the compiler shows error message

"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc1 in position 138: invalid start byte"

which is from

`classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)`

how can I solve this problem?

my code is as below..

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# training data and eveluation dala load
((train_data, train_labels),(eval_data, eval_labels)) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

train_data = train_data/np.float32(255)
train_labels = train_labels.astype(np.int32)

eval_data = eval_data/np.float32(255)
eval_labels = eval_labels.astype(np.int32)

feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column("x", shape=[28, 28])]

#logistic regression estimator
classifier = tf.estimator.LinearClassifier(
  feature_columns=feature_columns,
  n_classes=10,
  model_dir="mnist_model/"
)

#input_function
train_input_fn = tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    x={"x":train_data},
       y=train_labels,
          batch_size=100,
          num_epochs=None,
          shuffle=True)

classifier.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=10)
```

search google pages and stackoverflow questions.

Comment: 0xC1 is the start of a two byte code. What are the 6 bytes before this code? I suspect that the codes before makes it invalid. Please add the hex-output from position 132 to 139.